# I have a installed package Edit Quotas version 2.5 which is not working for new forecast type to edit quotas of a user

Tags: api, managed-package, error, appexchange, deprecated

**Installed Package Information:**

Package Name: Edit Quotas
Version: 2.5
Publisher: Salesforce.com

**Package Description:**

It is used to add or change quotas for forecast types.

**Issue :**

This package only supports the old forecast types and does not currently support the new forecast types. Also does not allow the editing of quotas for new forecast type. It gives below error when try to edit a user quotas in edit quotas tab.

**Error Message:**

Error: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_OPERATION, Use the current API version when inserting, updating, or deleting a quota value. Some features aren’t available in earlier API versions: []